# Conditional Variance Exercise

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

This is a simple exercise on Conditional Variance that I'm trying to understand the proof of.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables such that $Y$ is square-integrable. We call the random variable $\mathbf{E}\left((Y-\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X))^{2} \mid X\right)$ the conditional variance of $Y$ given $X$, denoted by $\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid X)$. Show that for all Borel measurable $f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ such that $f(X)$ is square-integrable,
> $$
> \mathbf{E}\left((Y-f(X))^{2}\right)=\mathbf{E}(\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid X))+\mathbf{E}\left((\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X)-f(X))^{2}\right).
> $$

Here is the solution, where I seem to be missing something simple.

> We have
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \mathbf{E}\left((Y-f(X))^{2}\right) &=\mathbf{E}\left([(Y-\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X))+(\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X)-f(X))]^{2}\right) \\
> &=\mathbf{E}\left((Y-\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X))^{2}\right)+2 \mathbf{E}((Y-\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X))(\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X)-f(X))) \\
> &+\mathbf{E}\left((\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X)-f(X))^{2}\right)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> The first term in the last line equals $\mathbf{E}(\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid X)),$ while the second term vanishes since $\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X)-f(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable. The proof is complete.

Okay, but what does $\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X)-f(X)$ being $\sigma(X)$-measurable have to do with anything? Why does it imply that $2 \mathbf{E}((Y-\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X))(\mathbf{E}(Y \mid X)-f(X))) = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired equation
$$
2\mathbb{E}\!\left[\left(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y \, | \, X]\right)\left(\mathbb{E}[Y \, | \, X] - f(x)\right)\right]
=
0
$$
may be rewritten as
$$
2\mathbb{E}\!\left[Y\left(\mathbb{E}[Y \, | \, X] - f(x)\right)-\mathbb{E}[Y\left(\mathbb{E}[Y \, | \, X] - f(x)\right) \, | \, X]\right]
=
0
$$
due to the stated measureabilility. This equation holds as a consequence of the law of iterated expectations. To see this, let $Z:=Y\left(\mathbb{E}[Y \, | \, X] - f(x)\right)$ and write
$$
\mathbb{E}\!\left[Z-\mathbb{E}[Z \, | \, X]\right] = \mathbb{E}[Z] - \mathbb{E}\!\left[\mathbb{E}[Z \, | \, X]\right] = \mathbb{E}[Z] - \mathbb{E}[Z] = 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I just confirm if we are using $-\mathbb{E}[Y \, | \, X]\left(\mathbb{E}[Y \, | \, X] - f(x)\right)
= -\mathbb{E}[Y\left(\mathbb{E}[Y \, | \, X] - f(x)\right) \, | \, X]$ as $\left(\mathbb{E}[Y \, | \, X] - f(x)\right)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable? (I'm new to conditional expectations)

Comment: Yes, indeed, @Albert.